# In JavaScript, how can you display a value of a variable immediately without a submit button?

Tags: php, html

In JavaScript, how can you display a value of a variable immediately without a submit button?

For example, if you where to do a simple calculator where the user would input the value of width and length to multiply them together without the need of a submit button. So lets say the interface is like

```
 width  length     sqft
[ 0 ]  * [ 0  ] =  [  0  ]
```

so when the user puts a value on both L and W sqft would immediately display the value which is (width*length)?

My calculator is more complex than that but I need to just remember the JavaScript syntax for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [`onkeyup`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onkeyup) event. Here's a quick example:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="example">
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("example").onkeyup = function(){
   console.log(this.value);
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xu3j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this OnKeyup, onKeyPress event